# Using mpv for video background on multiple monitors

Tags: archlinux, mplayer, i3, mpv

How can one use mpv to play a video as background on i3wm separately on 3 different screens/ workspaces?

I currently use 3 monitors on my i3 setup and wanted to use mpv to set up a live wallpaper.

The problem I am facing right now is that it plays in between two monitors and not on separate monitors/ workspaces as a background. I have used many commands but that's the closest I've got to it.

(hence this post):

`mpv --wid=0 --drm-connector=0.DP-1 /home/neo7798/Downloads/production\ ID_4818978.mp4`

(I was hoping it would at least play correctly on a single monitor with the other(still connected) monitors blank)

(You get the connector values by passing `mpv --drm-connector=help`)

Is there any way to play the video on separate screens in the background?

Can mplayer achieve this? I'm going to include --screen as well when I get back and give an update on it.

Update: same result even after using `--screen`:[image]

Comment: this might get a better response on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8rh9m3wOjk) for multiple monitors

And [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/mfqgcu/mpv_on_multiple_monitors/gss1paq?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) in case you are only interested in a single monitor config.